# How to make slick carousel images repeat infinitely

Tags: image, carousel

I have 6 images inside my slick carousel. They take full width space of the screen  but they don't repeat infinitely. To explain it further I mean that I want to use only 6 images and if they skip to the left overtime then they will appear from the right once again and again (They will keep repeating)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using bootstrap by any chance? because it has a built in carousel that can infinitely slide. Check out their code and see if you can imitate their logic.

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

Edit**

after looking further into it, does this help?

```
$('.multiple-items').slick({
  infinite: true,
});
```

referenced from: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

I haven't used slick before, but I believe you can set its' infinite property to true. Let me know if that works!

Comment: This is a bit more suited as a comment, since you don't really know if they are using Bootstrap.

Comment: Hello Chris, thanks for letting me know. still fairly new to SO and don't have enough reputation points to post a comment apparently. My apologies if I didn't follow guidelines.

Comment: Hi. I am using bootstrap but I want to create a different carousel/rotator. My carousel is showing a couple of photos at the same time (a group of photos instead of one). All the photos are stacked one next to another.

Comment: The important thing is that I have only 6 photos and they need to fill the entire width of the screen. It doesnt matter if there will always be 6 photos filling the width of the screen it is rather a carousel where they can REPEAT and repeating is very important. So they have their own size and it doesn't matter if there will be 3 of them filling the width of the screen or 10 of them. What matters the most is how to make them repeating so when the set of six photos will finish then another set of these photos will appearnext to them (like an infinite loop).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description, I think if you post the current code you are working with I might be able to get a clearer idea of what you are working with and want to achieve. 

Just to be clear, you want a set of 6 photos to be rendered on one slide and to just have it repeat itself over and over again on button clicks?

Answer (score 0):

```
in this fiddle the 'slidesToShow' is 6, so please make sure that your owl item is more than slidesToSwow count. So it will automatically working infinite loop option.
```

[Please visit fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x27381no/3/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).