# Slick: how to repeat infinitely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js

I have 4 images in total, that are all displayed on the screen. What I want, is once a user clicks on the next button to make 4th image to appear as 1st, while previously 1st picture would be now 2nd and so on.

This is a piece of my js code:

```
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
```

Infinite is set to true, but it does not work the way I want it if there are less than 5 images in total.

*I've searched for the answer here, and were able to find two similar questions, however both of them had no proper answer. Links for those:
[How to make slick carousel images repeat infinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208647/how-to-make-slick-carousel-images-repeat-infinitely) and [how could i make slides infinite (slick slider)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274246/how-could-i-make-slides-infinite-slick-slider)*.

Comment: How does it work? Seems to be all right with your piece of code...

Comment: @hering it works infinitely if i have 5 or more images but i only need to have 4

Comment: @RachelNicolas your code seems all right, would it be possible for you to post rest of the codes or share a jsfiddle ? that would make it easier for anyone to give an answer.

Comment: Have you tried the [W3 Schools Code](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp)?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't explain why that code doesn't work but here is a hot fix!

You can duplicate your set of images, so where you once had:

> A B C D

you now have:

> A B C D A B C D

This will now loop infinitely the way you want it to.

Comment: hmm it totally fixes this issue but unfortunately it can not be a solution in my case